# Two energy level classical system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

Consider a system of $N$ particles obeying classical statistics, each of which can have energy $0$ or $E$. The system is in thermal contact with a reservoir maintained at a temperature $T$. What will be the internal energy and heat capacity of the system?

I can't make head or tail out of it. I know that the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution function is $Ae^{-E/kT}$. In that $A$ depends upon the number of particles in the system. But when I substitute $0$ for energy $E$, $A$ becomes equal to the number of particles in state of energy $E$.

How can this question be approached? Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What matters is the energy difference between the levels, so the average N_E / N_0   will be A*exp(-Delta E/kT). Using the normalization condition N_E + N_0 = 1, you can obtain the expressions. I would give a proper answer, but I cannot at the moment.

Comment: @Vibin Narayanan,  this is a standard problem. Write down the canonical partition function, due to the degeneracy of states equals to the binomial coefficients, it has a simple form. Then, too, everything is standard, according to the formulas: ... logarithm, derivative, second derivative ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system is classical so the particles are distinguishable. In such a system ,you can just find out the single particle partition function which will then give you total partition function of the system.
Once the partition function is known ,energy and heat capacity can be found by taking some simple derivatives.

Comment: In this case you really can get total partition function of the system as a product of single particle  partition functions. But doing so it implies that distinguishable  particles are *independent* subsystems *unlike*  *indistinguishable*  particles. It looks somewhat strange to me since I thought that the independence of the subsystems is the result of absence of interaction

Comment: @Aleksey Druggist Yes,the independence is due to absence of interactions but for indistinguishable particles even if there is no interaction you cannot write total partition function as a product of single particle partition functions. That is what I meant.

Comment: Yes,I already assumed independence in my answer.

Comment: Of course, your answer is absolutely correct, it will be correct also if the number of energy levels is not two, but let's say $G$. But, when we go to the thermodynamic limit ($N\rightarrow\infty$,$G\rightarrow\infty$,  $N/G=const$), the calculated energy *will not be extensive* (proportional to $N$). This is the principle problem of distinguishable particles.